# PHP после расшифровки RSA не распознаёт русские буквы

Tags: php, openssl

```
openssl_private_decrypt(base64_decode("BYRF5p0/bUmp7w3JinVCsrOVhKeU+enFXJe+VCEGnwaT9lfZXrjU5aIEuhzJ1Mb4/MOFCZaiHJ0U53pg2TYrqw=="), $user, $pk);
```

$pk это приватный ключ $user - переменная для вывода, с английскими буквами работает идеально, но вместо русских выводит ������.
Что нужно делать?

Comment: Попробуйте `iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $str)`

Comment: Спасибо, заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего данные у вас в однобайтной кодировке(cp1251), а отображаете в utf-8.

Тогда нужно преобразовать кодировку для вывода:

```
$str = iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $str)
```